# FireFox localStorage reach maximum size while there are only 800 KB data in it

Tags: html, firefox, local-storage

I met an localStorage exception when I call API "localStorage.setItem()"

we are developing a web site, we used host like aaaa.bb.com the case is :

the localStorage already has about 560KB Data and then I want to set a new item into localStorage, the new item is a serialized Json Object, the size is about 301KB.

The way I used to test the size of localStorage is: JSON.stringify(localStorage).length

then the browser throw exception, the content of the exception is as follows:

"Persistent Storage maximum size reached" code:"1014" nsresult: "0x80530f6(NS_ERROR_DOM_QUOTA_REACHED)"

I tested this function in firefox on other machines and in chrome, this exception will not occur, I want to know why this exception occurs on the machine, if there is any settings in firefox? or if there is any relationship with the cache size?

Comment: 1. AFAIK it has no relationship with cache 2. what version of browser do you use? 3. I think it's clear, that you have to find another way to keep 100KB+ userdata

Comment: Finally I found the root cause.
the allocation of localStorage's space is different between chrome and firefox. 
in Chrome, aaa.domain.com and bbb.domain.com will each have 2.5M space, and they are separate.
 
while in firefox, although data in localStorage of each sub domain are separate, the total size of the sub-domains's localStorage under the same top level domain is 5M.

Comment: @MilesZhong You could convert your comment into an answer and accept it. This will help other users to see that the question has an answer and, as a nice side effect, you'll get the reputation for it. :)